# Image not loading from a particular resource - used Volley and Picasso

Tags: android, android-volley, picasso

A very peculiar problem seen when loading an image from the following URL:
https://codechef_shared.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/default/files/uploads/landing_page_banners/small-banner-updatedcook51.png

However I tried loading images from other sources and they loaded successfully. And there is no error reported!
I have used both picasso and volley's network image view for this URL and both are unable to load!

```
    Picasso.with(context).load("https://codechef_shared.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/default/files/uploads/landing_page_banners/small-banner-updatedcook51.png")
                .resize(200, 200).centerCrop()
                .into(viewHolder.ivEventImage);
```

Comment: I think your problem is `https://` the **S** cause it.

Comment: nope other images with https loaded successfully..

Comment: Which version of picasso are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrade image if is of large in size with the method :

```
ImageView myImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
  Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
  myImgView .setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
```

Comment: It is not a problem of the image being large.. I have loaded larger images in this method..
the problem in my case is the image is not being received after the request